# JQuery MultiSelect programmatic selection

Tags: jquery, multi-select

Using http://crlcu.github.io/multiselect/ I'm unable to programmatically 'reset' the 'from' & 'to' selections. Well, it works the first time, but then fails going forward.

The fiddle for this is https://jsfiddle.net/24690u7c/ . You can move things left & right without issue. The first time you hit the 'reset' button everything works. Then subsequent reset attempts just fail. The reset function does the following:

- move all items to the left
- select items that should be on the right
- move selected items on the left to the right

... the issue seems to be in the selection step: I see the 'selected' attribute getting set, but the items aren't seen as selected to the plugin.

Anyone able to tell me what I'm missing here?

```
$("#resetDefaults").on("click", function(event) {  
   $('#multiselect_leftAll').trigger('click');          // all to the left
   $("#multiselect option").each(function() {
     if ($(this).val() == "A"  || $(this).val() == "B") {
       $(this).attr('selected', true);                  // select what should be on the right
     }                                                  // ... this is I think the issue :-(
   });
   $('#multiselect_rightSelected').trigger('click');    // move the selected right
});
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, after tinkering with this, the simplest thing I can do to get this to work is to:

A) add `class='defaultColumn'` to each item I want to 'reset' over to the right selection

B) change the above snippet to the following:

```
 $("#resetDefaults").on("click", function(event) {
    $('#multiselect_leftAll').trigger('click');                  // all to the left
    var MS = $("#multiselect").data('crlcu.multiselect');        // grab the current Multiselect instance
    var $options = $("#multiselect").children('.defaultColumn'); // grab all options of interest
    MS.moveFromAtoB(MS.$left, MS.$right, $options);              // call the internal function to move the selected options over
 });
```

... I'm guessing this is the simplest. Thank heavens I chise a lib that was as clean as this one is :-)